# Does Android optimise for opaque views

Tags: android, optimization

As of 2013, is Android smart enough to not draw underlying backgrounds if a view is totally opaque? If so, how do you tell it that a view will always be opaque (in code, not in XML)? I have a `ListView` with an opaque background I want to make smoother.

[@RomainGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy) has an old 2009 post that says it doesn't, however he said he planned on adding in the feature. Did he?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but here are my 2c:

Lint still complains about redundant backgrounds. That is, it complains if you have a FrameLayout entirely filled by a ListView and set a background color on both. That suggests to me that nothing is being optimized away.

Also, I've done no real testing and this is completely anecdotal, but I "feel" like I saw a performance improvement when removing the bg color from the FrameLayout on a Fire HD (4.0.3).

Comment: The Kindle Fire HD uses a modified version of Android. It might not behave the same way

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally found [@RomainGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy)'s [blog](http://www.curious-creature.org/). While I couldn't find an exact answer there, it was covered in one [article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/). He talked about overdraw and, although didn't explicitly say it, implied that there was little if any optimisation going on.

From [the article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/), it seems clear eliminating overlapping drawing can be a huge performance boost. There is even a tool in the SDK to check how much such overdraw is happening.